# Azure Keyvault secret auto rotation and notification before expiry

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-keyvault

Looking for an automated way to set notification for Azure Keyvault secret expiry before 1 month of time and renew the expiry date on approval based from the Azure Devops pipeline side or any way in automated process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use Azure DevOps, you can integrate it with Event Grid and Automation account to meet your needs.

1. Receive Key Vault notifications through Event Grid.
2. Azure KeyVault event triggers Automation account's Runbook through webhook. Runbook triggers DevOps pipeline through Azure DevOps REST API "[Runs - Run Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run-pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1)".
3. DevOps pipeline uses an Environment to set approver and run Azure PowerShell to update the expiration time of a secret.

**For the first and second steps**, refer to the detailed steps in the documentation [Receive and respond to key vault notifications with Azure Event Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/event-grid-tutorial).

a. When you create your runbook, replace your runbook with the following scripts. Also, replace the values in {}.

```
param
(
[Parameter (Mandatory = $false)]
[object] $WebhookData
)

#If runbook was called from Webhook, WebhookData will not be null.
if ($WebhookData) {
#Run Azure DevOps REST API to trigger the pipeline
$token = "{Azure DevOps PAT}"
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
$url="https://dev.azure.com/{Azure DevOps Org name}/{Project name}/_apis/pipelines/{Pipeline id}/runs?api-version=7.1-preview.1"
$body = @'
{
    "stagesToSkip": [],
    "resources": {
        "repositories": {
            "self": {
                "refName": "refs/heads/main"
            }
        }
    },
    "variables": {}
}
'@
$head = @{ Authorization =" Basic $token" }
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Post -Headers $head -Body $body -ContentType application/json
}
else
{
# Error
write-Error "No input data found." 
}
```

b. When you create an Event Grid subscription in your KeyVault, set the "Filter to Event Types" to **SecretNearExpiry**.

**For the third step**:

a. Create an environment without any resource and add an approver from [Approvals and checks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals?view=azure-devops&tabs=check-pass#approvals).
[image]

b. Create a pipeline using the following yaml.

```
jobs:
- deployment: Deploy
  displayName: deploy KeyVault
  pool:
    vmImage: 'windows-latest'
  environment: 'KeyVault'
  strategy: 
    runOnce:
      deploy:
        steps:
         - task: AzurePowerShell@5
           inputs:
             azureSubscription: '{ARM service connection used to access your KeyVault}'
             ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
             Inline: |
                $Expires = (Get-Date).AddYears(2).ToUniversalTime()
                Update-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName '{Your KeyVault Name}' -Name '{Your Secret Name}' -Expires $Expires
             azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
```

When the pipeline is triggered, it will need to be approved by an approver before it can run.
[image]

If the operation of updating the secret does not require approval, you can directly use the automation account's runbook to update the expiration time. Besides, you can also consider using Azure Function app. Refer to [Automate the rotation of a secret for resources that use one set of authentication credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/tutorial-rotation) and [Automate the rotation of a secret for resources that have two sets of authentication credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/tutorial-rotation-dual?tabs=azurepowershell) for the detailed info.

Comment: can we use same eventgrid, runbook and webhook for multiple keyvaults. In that case, how the triggers will be initaiated to the ado pipeline?

Comment: Also, how the expiration will be notified over mail ?

Comment: Also getting Below error. Seems this webhook will not work for azuredevops server. $url = "https://myadoserver.com/devops/myorganization/myproject/_apis/pipelines/625/runs?api-version=7.0"
 myadoserver.com No such host is known.

Comment: For different KeyVaults, you need to create different events. If you select the same webhook as the endpoint, it may cause some issues. In the existing runbook, it only triggers the pipeline through the REST API, and does not pass the secret that is currently about to expire and the corresponding KeyVault value. For the time being, I haven't found a way to pass these two values ​​before the pipeline is compiled. After adding environment approver in Azure DevOps, you will receive email notification when the pipeline is triggered.

Comment: For multiple KeyVaults or multiple secrets, you can run `Update-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName '{Your KeyVault Name}' -Name '{Your Secret Name}' -Expires $Expires` directly in the runbook or function app to update your secret. You can get the KeyVault name and secret name in `WebhookData`.  But I'm not sure if the runbook and function app have a similar approval functionality.