# Azure runbook to Azuredevops server pipeline trigger failing

Tags: azure, azure-devops-server-2019, azure-runbook

We are following the answer provided in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77539069/azure-keyvault-secret-auto-rotation-and-notification-before-expiry/77541367#77541367) and trying to automate the secret expiry notification of our key vaults and enable auto rotation of secrets using azuredevops pipelines.

We are getting "No such host is known" error while we are trying to invoke the azuredevops server pipeline hosted in on premise from the azure runbook automation script.

```
param
(
[Parameter (Mandatory = $false)]
[object] $WebhookData
)

#If runbook was called from Webhook, WebhookData will not be null.
if ($WebhookData) {
#Run Azure DevOps REST API to trigger the pipeline
$token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
$url = "https://myado.com/devops/myorganization/myproject/_apis/build/builds?api-version=6.0"
$body = @"
{
    `"definition`":  {
                       `"id`":  xxxxx
                   }
}
"@
$head = @{ Authorization =" Basic $token" }
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Post -Headers $head -Body $body -ContentType application/json
}
else
{
# Error
write-Error "No input data found." 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The request URI is in the following form:

`VERB https://{instance}[/{team-project}]/_apis[/{area}]/{resource}?api-version={version}`.

For Azure DevOps server, the instance is `{server:port}/tfs/{collection}`. See [Components of a REST API request/response pair](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2#components-of-a-rest-api-requestresponse-pair) for the detailed info.

Take my server as an example. The following is the URL of the project seen on the UI.
[image]

Copy the URL directly from the brower and the request URL will be `http://vziy***/DefaultCollection/Pro1/_apis/build/builds?api-version=6.0`

Comment: In our case also. I copied the url from the directly from the browser itself. Even I tried with IP address of ado server. Whether Azure runbook to onprem hosted azuredevops server will work or supported ?

Comment: any guidance on this issue? I am able to invoke the pipeline using same API from postman, but from runbook its not working.

Comment: or is there any way to invoke the same API from a server which is having access to the  the ADO server pipeline API

Comment: According to the current situation, it seems that the Azure Automation account cannot access your local server. The Azure Automation account uses public ip but your local server is using private ip. You need to ensure that it can access your local server before it runs API to trigger the pipeline. This requires configuring the network between them. You just want to automatically update the secret's expiry date, why not consider using Azure DevOps Service directly? This way you don't need to config the network.

Comment: We dont have azuredevops service and as per our policy, we have to use azuredevops server

Comment: If so, you need to config the network between Automation account and your local server. (I am not very familiar with this) Check if [Azure Automation network configuration details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-network-configuration) helps. Or you can use Automation account or Function app to update the secret instead of Azure DevOps.